# Maintaining long term persistant socket connection over wireless internet connection issues Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcpclient, winsock2

I'm having a big issue keeping a persistant socket connection working over several wireless internet providers on client PC's running Windows XP, Vista, and 8.1.

What I want to happen: The client PC read data from a sensor on the serial port then send the sensor messages to the server over ethernet/IP. When the internet connection is broken my client application recognizes this and tries to establish a new connection. This needs to happen automatically, 24 hours a day. The serial sensor outputs several data messages once per second. I need this data ontime not stored and delayed.

What does happen: All goes well untill the internet connection is broken multiple times or for a stretch of time. The client tries to create a new connection. After some time or just many hours of operation with short wireless disconnects the client quits being able to open any ports. Eventually Windows resets all the ports and it works again for most of a day or so depending on the wireless internet. Appearently Windows OS resets the ports around 12pm local PC clock time as all non functional remote clients suddenly are able to connect back to the server around that time.

What I have found: My first try allowed the OS to find the first available user socket port number to use. After a long time of running a client with bad login info so it would get regeted by the server and try again over and over, and watching netstat output, I found the client would go through the available port numbers untill the top port number the system had for users was reached. Windows then just stopped assigning a port to the client to use untill the OS resets all ports later that day.
So I tried something different. I used bind to lock the client onto a specific port. Veriying this with netstat it appeared to work but eventually I had the same OS  issue. I'm not sure what to do to make this better. I have set the registry to TcpTimedWaitDelay = 1 second.

This is a basic code that I am trying now. There are returns from this function for errors from every stage.

```
int check;
if(Socket != INVALID_SOCKET)  //if not closed then close socket
{
    closesocket(Socket);
    Socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}
time_f timer = getTimePrecise();
//wait 5 second before reconnect attempt
while(getTimePrecise() - timer < 5.0){}
//set Windows reg to 1 second TcpTimedWaitDelay

ZeroMemory(&hints,  sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family   = AF_INET;  //use IPv4
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
ZeroMemory(&hints2, sizeof(hints2));
hints2.ai_family   = AF_INET;  //use IPv4
hints2.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints2.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints2.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
check = getaddrinfo(serverADDR , serverPORT, &hints2, &outbound);
check = getaddrinfo(NULL , DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &local);
Socket = socket( local->ai_family, local->ai_socktype, local->ai_protocol);
check = bind(Socket, local->ai_addr, (int)local->ai_addrlen);
check = ioctlsocket(Socket, FIONBIO, &NonBlock);
char value = 0;
check = setsockopt( Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DONTLINGER, &value, sizeof( value ) );
value = 1;
check = setsockopt( Socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &value, sizeof( value ) );
cout << "attempting connect" << endl;
check = connect(Socket, outbound->ai_addr, outbound->ai_addrlen);
if(check == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    check = WSAGetLastError();
    if(check == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) // then set a timeout
    {
        fd_set Write, Err;
        TIMEVAL Timeout;
        int TimeoutSec = 10; // timeout after 10 seconds
        FD_ZERO(&Write);
        FD_ZERO(&Err);
        FD_SET(Socket, &Write);
        FD_SET(Socket, &Err);
        Timeout.tv_sec = TimeoutSec;
        Timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        check = select(0, NULL, &Write, &Err, &Timeout);
        if(check == 0)
        {
            printf("connect call to server, select call timeout elapsed\r\n");
            closesocket(Socket);
            freeaddrinfo(local);
            freeaddrinfo(outbound);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(Socket, &Write) )
            {
                freeaddrinfo(local);
                freeaddrinfo(outbound);
                cout << "socket opened to server, after wait" << endl;
                return true;
            }
            if(FD_ISSET(Socket, &Err) )
            {
                printf("connect call to server, select call error state\r\n");
                closesocket(Socket);
                freeaddrinfo(local);
                freeaddrinfo(outbound);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(check == WSAECONNREFUSED)
    {
        cout << "no server program at requested address " << serverADDR << endl;
        closesocket(Socket);
        freeaddrinfo(local);
        freeaddrinfo(outbound);
        return false;
    }
    else if(check == WSAEHOSTDOWN || check == WSAETIMEDOUT)
    {
        cout << "no server present at requested address " << serverADDR << endl;
        closesocket(Socket);
        freeaddrinfo(local);
        freeaddrinfo(outbound);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "connect call WSA error code " << check << endl;
        closesocket(Socket);
        freeaddrinfo(local);
        freeaddrinfo(outbound);
        return false;
    }
}//end socket error
//else instant connection is good
cout << "socket opened to server instantly" << endl;
freeaddrinfo(local);
freeaddrinfo(outbound);
return true;
```

I thought about adding this to see if it would help out.

```
value = 1;
check = setsockopt( Socket, IPPROTO_TCP, SO_REUSEADDR, &value, sizeof( value ) );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The thing with wireless is that's its not reliable. I always setup a timer and If no data is received in my defined interval i will kill the socket and try to reconnect. A simple counter of the bytes received on each read works to indicate no data received.....start timer and if no more data received in your prdefined interval....close and restart socket. Or switch to UDP.